# Unresolved Reference - Developer Training

Tags: android, kotlin

I am going through the Developer training on android.com and I've run into a snag. I've entered some code (shown below) and used Alt+Enter to resolve all my reference issues except one. This issue is not mentioned in the instructions and I can't proceed without fixing it so I'm asking for any help available. It's on line 21 the word "edittext" highlighted in red.

[image: My broken code]

The training page with the instructions is here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Thank you!

Comment: Check if you `activity_main` layout file has any `EditText` with `android:id="@+id/editText"`

Comment: @TamHuynh thank you for the information. You were right on target with your information. Most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take one `EditText` with id `android:id="@+id/editText"` in your  `activity_main.xml` layout file

LIKE THIS

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Well you lead me right to it! Thank you so very much. My issue is that my android:id was as follows: android:id="@+id/editText2 and I think that's because, in doing the training, I removed and readded the textbox as I had made a mistake. Apparently it doesn't reuse the ID even though the field has been deleted. I updated the reference to point at the right id and it's working great! Thank you!